# Which block explorers recognize bech32 addresses?

Tags: segregated-witness, bech32-address, blockchain-explorer

At this time, blockchain.info doesn't. Neither does blockchair or blockcypher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Blockchair announced support for Bech32 addresses last month](https://twitter.com/Blockchair/status/932717919062118401).

This page about [Bech32 adoption](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption#Blockchain_Explorers) on bitcoin.it wiki page is tracking blockexplorers that support Bech32 addresses.

Comment: Looks like blockchain.info can decode bech32 if you select "show scripts..." aka Advanced mode. But doesn't seem to be able to search for a bech32 address

Comment: https://blockchain.info/tx/c23248b87ae5f1533e62d4e5f99ac4373a209a38050ac78b1c84b8b7b8d91b1f but yes, it can't search.